# Apache Nifi TailFile missing last line

Tags: apache-nifi

I am trying to create a pipeline for delivering log files through **Apache Nifi**. For now i'v been able to set up proper log handling using
**TailFile** -> **ConvertRecord** (**GrokReader** and **JsonWriter**) -> **SplitJson**

The problem i am dealing now is that **TailFile** appears to look for carriage return to tail file. So then the last line of the log will always be missing

whel tailing something like:

```
2020-04-10 13:39:16,670 ERROR HomeController 1 logline

2020-04-10 13:44:29,476 ERROR HomeController 2 logline

2020-04-10 13:44:35,343 ERROR HomeController 3 logline

2020-04-10 13:44:37,981 ERROR HomeController 4 logline
```

i always get:

```
2020-04-10 13:39:16,670 ERROR HomeController 1 logline

2020-04-10 13:44:29,476 ERROR HomeController 2 logline

2020-04-10 13:44:35,343 ERROR HomeController 3 logline
```

Delivering every line is crutial to me. Is there a way to to pick up logs in other way?

**GetFile** is a bad option. It is possible that files will be up to 1-2 Gb size before rotated.

Comment: why there is no a new line at the end of file?

Comment: @daggett, you are absolutely right. I checked every needed log files ant there is always trailing new line charater. Thank you